# SQL Server function return only first character

Tags: sql-server-2008

I wrote a SQL Server function which should return full column data like 
`Jhon` but for unknown reasons, it returns only the first character like `J`

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_GET_USER_INFO(@param1 VARCHAR(60))
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @vResult VARCHAR

    SELECT @vRESULT = column1
    FROM table1 
    WHERE UPPER(column1) = UPPER(@param1) 

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
        SET @vResult = @vResult
    ELSE
        SET @vResult = -1

    RETURN @vResult
END
```

Comment: @JonE i tried to change it to varchar(60) that was not help

Comment: Also change  DECLARE @vResult VARCHAR  to be  (60)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should ***always*** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use! Otherwise, a parameter will default to **1 character length** .....

Comment: @marc_s  the answer of the old question is not complete or clear enough it please look at the answer I have posted

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved by adding the `datatype` size **`RETURNS VARCHAR(60)`** not only for the `return` part and for the declared variable too **`DECLARE @vResult VARCHAR(60)`**
as shown below

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_Function_Name(@param1 VARCHAR(60))

RETURNS VARCHAR(60)
AS 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @vResult VARCHAR(60)

SELECT @vRESULT=column1
    FROM table1 
WHERE  UPPER(column1)=UPPER(@param1) 

IF @@ROWCOUNT=1
    SET @vResult=@vResult
ELSE
    SET @vResult= -1

RETURN @vResult
END
```